# function export in es6 got unexpected token

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I want to turn this

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
module.exports = sum;
```

into es6. I have babel preset 2015 but I still got error when I try to run below code:

```
export default sum(a, b) => {
    return a + b;
}
```

Anything wrong with my es6 function and export?

Answer (score 1):

It would either be

```
const sum = (a, b) => {
   return a + b;
};

export default sum
```

or

```
export default (a, b) => {
  return a + b;
};
```

You can also try it out here: https://babeljs.io/repl, and see the transpiled code.

Comment: The first one would result in an error as `sum` would need to be defined first. `const sum = ...; export default sum;` however would work.

Comment: @CodingIntrigue Seems to be okay - https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&code='use%20strict'%3B%0A%0Aexport%20default%20sum%20%3D%20(a%2C%20b)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20a%20%2B%20b%3B%0A%7D%3B

Comment: Babel compiles fine, but you'd get a runtime `ReferenceError`. ES Modules run in Strict Mode and implicitly created global variables are not allowed. `let sum; export default sum = ...` would also get around that issue.

Comment: Yeah, the first one is not what you want. It similar to doing `return sum = 42;` from a function.